# How to Secure Spring Rest Services with Spring Sercurity and Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, rest, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring MVC Server Backend with Rest-Services and an AngularJS WebFrontend.

i want to secure my spring mvc rest services but i want use java config.. and i have no idea how the configuration mus look like. Can someone help me with this ?
The only good implementation i have found is this : https://github.com/philipsorst/angular-rest-springsecurity

I use a postgrsDB and i wand store username and password and roles there, is the session token in the example from https://github.com/philipsorst/angular-rest-springsecurity only stored in cache and not in the db ?

At the moment i have a simple form login security, this was only for testing, but i did not use jsp i use only the spring mvc rest services and angularjs as webfrontend.. How can i modify my spring security code that it works with oauth2 like in the example from https://github.com/philipsorst/angular-rest-springsecurity ? I have at the moment only this two classes from spring security..

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("username").password("test").roles("User");
    }
}
```

and then i register the securityConfig in my WebInitializer.

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{ PersistenceContext.class,AppConfig.class,SecurityConfig.class }; 
} ....
```

But the roles and username/password should stored in a database.. must i use a special databse schema for spring security to store username,password and roles in my db ?

And can i implement it so that i can only add the @Secured Annotation(or any other Annotation) over one of my rest services with the role in it ? Like @Secured("UserRole")

Or ist Basic Authentification easier ? can i secure my rest services with basic authentification with rolemanagement !? if so we can use basic authentification..
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

In order to load users you have to create an authentication manager and wire a UserDetailsService into that authentication manager.  The following doc link gives a good overview of authentication manager, and the core components associated.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#core-services

So, to answer your first question...

> But the roles and username/password should stored in a database.. must i use a special 
>   databse schema for spring security to store username,password and roles in my db ?

You can do either.  If you want, spring security can handle all the database side for you, you just have to supply a reference to a JDBC datasource which has Spring's schema design.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#core-services-jdbc-user-service

and

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-schema

-or-

You can utilize your own schema by providing a UserDetailsService implementation of your own that will load from your own database schema.  Here's some samples that can get you started with that approach.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.security" />
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

<bean id="dao-provider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider"
      p:userDetailsService-ref="myUserDetailsService"
      p:passwordEncoder-ref="sha-pw-encoder"
      p:saltSource-ref="my-salt-source" />

<bean id="sha-pw-encoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder"
      p:encodeHashAsBase64="true" />

<bean id="my-salt-source" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource"
      p:userPropertyToUse="salt" />

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="dao-provider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Finally, provide an implementation of the UserDetailsService like so:

```
@Component("myUserDetailsService")
public class MyUserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

//Reference to the spring JPA repository for loading users
private final UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
public MyUserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException         {
    User user = userRepository.findByName(username);
    if (user != null) {
        return new UserDetails() {
          ... //create the user details from the user object
        }
    } else {
        String err = String.format("Failed to find username: %s in local database.  Trying other auth mechanisms.", username);
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(err);
    }
  }
}
```

... for your second question:

> And can i implement it so that i can only add the @Secured Annotation(or any other 
>   Annotation) over one of my rest services with the role in it ? Like @Secured("UserRole")

Yes, the above configuration will allow you to use @Secured annotation by configuring the global-method-security.

And finally, yes all of this will still utilize basic authentication by default, but can be reconfigured to use digest authentication if necessary.  I recommend giving a full read to the docs at http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/ in order to really grasp what you're trying to do.  But, this should get you on your way.

Comment: Hm i did not use JPA in my Project and i have no xml files. The Security Schema is not so good i want not the username as Primary Key i want a normal ID as Integer and then username password. Hoq can i convert the xml above to java !?

Comment: I use Jooq as my Database Mapping Layer http://www.jooq.org and no JPA or DAOs but jooq can generate DAOS but i have no idea if this works with spring.. Can i do the User Service withou JPA ? How can i convert this: "bean id="dao-provider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider"
      p:userDetailsService-ref="myUserDetailsService"
      p:passwordEncoder-ref="sha-pw-encoder"
      p:saltSource-ref="my-salt-source" />" To my Jooq implementations without JPA ?

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed that you were doing Java config at first.... So, you should be able to do the following:  1) Create the UserDetailsService implementation as I suggested above.  2) Instead of auth.inMemoryAuthentication() call auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService), passing in your own user details service reference.  3) You can make your UserDetailsService to use whatever method you want to load usernames, whether you use jooq or not should be irrelevant, as long as you can load a user object, and then convert your user format into a UserDetails object which is what is required.

Comment: Can you make an Exemple of such a UserDetails object? I have 2 Tables one is Account with id(as Primary Key), username, password and a role_ID as Foreignt Key. The Second table is roles_lookup with role_id as Primary Key and rolename.. In the Table role_lookup is role_id 1 ="admin" and role_id 2= "user". The Foreignt Key from the Account Table links to the roles_lookup table. Can i use this Tabes for a userdetailsservice ? How can i create a User Object with jdbc and my tables ?